# Не могу войти в систему Linux Mint

Tags: пароль, логин

Ввожу логин и пароль, появляется консоль и опять окно ввода логина.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, проблема в видеодрайвере. Я так понял, что в консоль (текстовую) войти можно? Ну, смотрите логи! Через Alt-F1 в консоль войти попробуйте!

Comment: Да, проблема действительно в видеодрайвере. Но как его исправить или переустановить? (из под текстовой консоли)

Answer (score 0):

Неверно вводите логин/пароль. Если проблема остается в этом, пароль пользователя (root) можно сбросить с помощью Live-CD.

Comment: К сожелению проблема не в этом. Логин и пароль точно верные поскольку если ввести не правильный логин или пароль появится надпись что логин или пароль неверные. Тоесть логин\пароль принимается и после этого в консоли checking battery (или что-то подобное) и опять окно ввода логина.